# Simple VBA Macro, Allow user to insert custom number

Tags: vba, excel

Where my macro inputs `29301` into the filter, I would like to start a dialogue box in which the user could input their own number to filter.

```
Sub Macro3()
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$CL$293662").AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:= _
    "=29301", Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

Comment: Do something like `number=application.inputbox("enter number to filter")` then use `number` in your filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. Comments in the code.

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim retval

    'Get a value, very simple input box
    retval = InputBox("Please enter a number to filter by")

    'Make sure the data is numeric
    If IsNumeric(retval) = False Then
        MsgBox "You didn't enter a number! Try again"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Apply the filter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$CL$293662").AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="=" & retval
End Sub
```